# R Package developmnet error with devtools::build_win()

Tags: r, curl, package, devtools

I'm trying to package an R library. Everything was working fine. However, after some update I started getting the following error:

```
Error: ‘curl’ is not in Suggests: for pkgload!
```

in the use of `devtools::build_win()`.

**Edited**

It was a bug in development version of `devtools`. Reported ([See here](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/issues/1604#issuecomment-327179594)) and have be fixed ([See here](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/commit/a0c8d7333be185f979a60823dcfad66c9f3ea35e)).

Comment: I would guess one of your functions calls a `curl` function and you've maybe not realised. Try `devtools::use_package("curl", type = "Suggests")`

Comment: I'm getting the same error today. And so I added the package to my descriptions file under Suggests, but to no avail!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like a lot of us, your probably on the Github Version: 1.13.3.9000.
Do this:

`install.packages("devtools")`

This will get your back to version 1.13.3.
This worked for me, let me know if it works for you too!